# Hibernate Lazy Loading makes criteria slow to run

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am experiencing a problem with hibernate and lazy loading of objects.
basically I want to load an class which has an eagerly loaded field and not load the lazy fields of child classes

Take the following QuestionVO class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class QuestionVO extends BaseDAOVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5867047752936216092L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "questionText", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 4000)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 4000)
    @Pattern(regexp = MobileAppsRegexConstants.GENERAL_ALLOWED_CHARCHTERS, message = "Question Text Not valid.")
    private String questionText;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "MENU_STYLE_ID", nullable = true)
    private MenuStyleVO menuStyle;

    }
```

Take the following MenuStyleVO class

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "menu_style")
public class MenuStyleVO extends BaseDAOVO implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3697798179195096156L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "menuStyleName", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String menuStyleName;

    @Column(name = "menuTemplate", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String menuTemplate;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @JoinColumn(name="logo_id")
    @JsonProperty("logo")
    private ApplicationImageVO logo;


    }
```

And this ApplicationImageVO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_image")
public class ApplicationImageVO extends BaseDAOVO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9158898930601867545L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "image1242x2208")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnore
    private SubmissionLauncherImagesVO launcherImage1242x2208;  

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "image1536x2048")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnore
    private SubmissionLauncherImagesVO launcherImage1536x2048;  

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "image2048x1536")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnore
    private SubmissionLauncherImagesVO launcherImage2048x1536;  

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "logo")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonIgnore
    private MenuStyleVO menuStyleLogo; 

    }
```

If L load the QuestionVO class from the database using the following hibernate criteria code - all the lazy fields of MenuStyleVO and ApplicationImageVO are also loaded.

On complicated use cases, this results in this query getting very slow

```
public QuestionVO findMasterAppQuestionById(int id) {

    Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(QuestionVO.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

    QuestionVO questionVO  = (QuestionVO) criteria.uniqueResult();

    return questionVO;
}
```

What I am wondering is - would it be possible to load the QuestionVO class and its eager fields and tell hibernate to ignore lazy fields from the other classes bar those that are needed?

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time we faced an issue like this we used a constructor on parent class, which use only the desired fields of determined query.

I can't remember in fully how constructor inside a jpql query works, but it must be something like this:

```
select new com.package.class(c.field1, c.field2) from com.package.class c
```

Remember, a constructor with same arguments must be present on the desired entity.

Pros:
- Better query perfomance;
- Can be replicated with other arguments;

Cons:
- Pretty limited, you can only use this hack on the main entity you are querying;
- Includes a constructor only for determined query, poor design;

Also, you should take a look on EnttyGraphs of JPA. Seems quite promising, but didn't work as desired in our project.

Btw, Hibernate has put us many times on performance issues, hope this hack help you, good luck!

Edit:

Why this pattern would help in performance issues?
Basically, with the example i've showed before, you are not loading everything via Hibernate, only the two fields (field1 and field2) of the main entity. Without using a constructor you shoudn't be able to do that, because your query would not result in a collection of the desired entity, but in a collection of two objects each iteration (Object[]). Using the constructor pattern you are creating instances of the desired entity, but only selecting a few fields from database, and that's why this pattern can help you, you are returning a collection of the desired entity with only a few fields.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. Im not sure how a contructor can help here if we load everything via hibernate. can you explain further please?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check it out.

Comment: hI - thanks for the update. i see what you mean of this being a hack. its possible so it is but hopefully someone may come up with another alternative. All the same - your input is much appreciated

Comment: That's alright, sadly Hibernate can be used by way too many types of implementation, I would say it's nearly impossible to one give one solution that would work in every Hibernate project, let's see if other people gives us other alternatives to this problem.

Comment: I completely understand. These performance issues can be slightly frustrating at times. Hopefully some other alternatives will appear that will suit both our needs

Comment: would the @Fetch annotation help in any way here?

Comment: Yeah it would. Setting @Fetch type LAZY to a mapped attribute will make Hibernate load only a reference of this relantionship, and not all it's attributes. Personally I do not like this approach because everytime you try to access an attribute of this relation you will get a LazyInitializationException if you do not explicit fetch the desired attribute on your query.