# Hibernate fetch optimization issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have a legacy database where a single top level table has many relationships and sub-relationships.  We usually don't need all or most of them and we set them to lazy load by default, and then use joins in HQL to pre-fetch the ones we're going to need in a particular part of the code.

We've got a module where we need quite a few of these.  We don't want to get into N+1, but we've hit a massive performance snafu with this approach where one record has almost 4000 children, and they in turn have varying numbers of children.  We have tried lazy-loading as many as we can without getting into N+1, but it appears that the cross-product that the join is producing is just unrealistically large.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?  It seems like what is needed is a way to break this joined query into multiple queries, and then piece the hibernate models together in their relationships as a second step.  Like if there was a way to do the HQL to load tables A, B, and C, but then make the load of C's sub-detail a second step that hibernate applies to the hierarchy by key.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you would like to read about the [constructor pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540507/hibernate-lazy-loading-makes-criteria-slow-to-run/32540782#32540782)